# JSONLoader object linking - URL works fine, relative path is not

Tags: javascript, three.js

Got a simple and stubborn problem here with THREE.js and I need help.

I noticed that when I link a three.js 3D object passing an URL, everything seems working fine. But when I pass a relative path, only black window appears.
Working code below:

```
        var jsLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        jsLoader.load('http://codepen.io/nickpettit/pen/nqyaK.js', function(geometry) {
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();
            var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);
            mesh.scale.set(10,10,10);
        });
```

And when I try to use 'models/model.js' instead (which is just a copy of an object located in the mentioned URL), it is not working.

I'm sure that this path is correct, cause I've linked three.js build file in a similar manner (which is located in 'js/three.js'). What am I doing wrong?

PS I'm working on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [this page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally). You're facing *[same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)* restriction to load from a file system. In addition to the solutions said in the page, you can setup an *AMP* local server, and address your pages in the browser through *localhost*.

*Andreas Anyuru* has explained the reason for *same origin policy* for textures in his book *[Professional WebGL Programming](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-1119968860.html)* (page 214); the same applies for models as well:

> During the development of the specification, security expert Steve Baker pointed out that it might be possible to figure out the content of the texture by writing a special fragment shader that is then uploaded to the GPU when the user visits a malicious site. The fragment shader could measure the time it takes to test the color of a texel, and from this time it could calculate the brightness of the texel in the texture. There also has been a proof of concept implementation that demonstrated that this attack is actually possible in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing...

The path is relative to the location of the javascript file.

Let's say the js file is in `/lib/app.js`, the path to the model is `../models/model.js`.

The easiest is to always use local absolute paths, like `/models/model.js`.

It is working when you link three.js build file because your html file is likely at the root, so `lib/three.js` is the same as `/lib/three.js`

If you had used the network debugger, you should see it is not a three.js problem, but really a path problem :)